# using connector in webots

Tags: connector, webots

I want to simulate an environment which a robot grab a box and transport it. 
robot must grab box from any point it want but it's not possible with a grabber so I thought maybe I can use a connector on robot and another connector on box and set it's length and width large enough and the angles of connecting to 180 degree to let robot grab it any way it want. I define box as robot node to put connector on it but the robot don't connect to box when it is close enough. 
I thought maybe something like this is not possible, is it? Can I use a connector to take a box by a robot?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, your want the robot to be able to grab the box from any of the 4 sides it will approach the box. If so, I would recommend you to set a Connecter device on each side of the box and another Connector device on the robot. All connectors should have a large range of distance and angle to allow connection. This way, your robot should be able to grab the box from any side.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Yes,exactly. I want to do that. 
I couldn't set the connector to a box, So I defined box as a robot node. Then I set a connector with a large range to it but it didn't work. Robot has an arm. This arm comes close enough to box, but it doesn't connect to box!!! I thought maybe doing something like that isn't possible.
I'm new with webots, how can I find out why it doesn't work?